# Rendering Videos in iOS using Metal / OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, rendering, metal

How can I render Videos  using Metal or OpenGL ES?

I'm talking about **decoding** and **displaying** **the** **frames** by myself.

I am very new to `Metal` and `OpenGL ES` and I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're asking isn't trivial for someone just getting started with this, so you might want to break this down into smaller parts. That said, I have done this and can describe the general process.

First, you'll start with an AVAssetReader and set up AVAssetReaderOutputs for the audio and video tracks. From those, you iterate through the CMSampleBufferRefs. For each video frame, you'll extract a CVImageBufferRef.

Uploading the video frames to OpenGL textures can go a couple of different ways. The most performant path is to work with YUV data and upload the Y and UV planes via iOS's texture caches. You'll then use a YUV -> RGB shader to combine these planes and convert to the RGB colorspace for processing or display.

You could also work with BGRA data from the movie file and upload that directly into a texture, but there's more overhead to that process. It is simpler, though, and avoids the need for a manual color conversion shader.

After that, you'll take your texture and render it to a quad using a passthrough vertex and fragment shader, or you could do shader-based processing on the video.

Similar processes and pathways exist for uploading to Metal, and the starting point is the same.

Now, if you don't want to implement all that by hand, I've written an open source framework called GPUImage that encapsulates this. It comes in [Objective-C](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and [Swift](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2) varieties. If you don't want to pull the entire framework, focus on the GPUImageMovie (for the former) or the MovieInput (for the latter) classes. They contain all the code needed to do this, so you can extract the implementations there and use them directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It would have taken me weeks to even come up with a proof of concept.

Comment: hello there @Brad Larson, can your project be used on displaying multiple stream from RTSP?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the simplest, fastest way to get started:

```
@import UIKit;
@import AVFoundation;
@import CoreMedia;
#import <MetalKit/MetalKit.h>
#import <Metal/Metal.h>
#import <MetalPerformanceShaders/MetalPerformanceShaders.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MTKViewDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>  {
    NSString *_displayName;
    NSString *serviceType;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) SessionContainer *session;
@property (retain, nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *avSession;

@end;

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    MTKView *_metalView;

    id<MTLDevice> _device;
    id<MTLCommandQueue> _commandQueue;
    id<MTLTexture> _texture;

    CVMetalTextureCacheRef _textureCache;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice;
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t sessionQueue;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    _metalView = [[MTKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [_metalView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    _metalView.device = _device;
    _metalView.delegate = self;
    _metalView.clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 1, 1, 1);
    _metalView.colorPixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    _metalView.framebufferOnly = NO;
    _metalView.autoResizeDrawable = NO;

    CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(NULL, NULL, _device, NULL, &_textureCache);

    [self.view addSubview:_metalView];

    self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL );

    if ([self setupCamera]) {
        [_avSession startRunning];
    }
}

- (BOOL)setupCamera {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    @try {
        NSError * error;

            _avSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
            [_avSession beginConfiguration];
            [_avSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

            // get list of devices; connect to front-facing camera
            self.videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            if (self.videoDevice == nil) return FALSE;

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.videoDevice error:&error];
            [_avSession addInput:input];

            dispatch_queue_t sampleBufferQueue = dispatch_queue_create("CameraMulticaster", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

            AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * dataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
            [dataOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
            [dataOutput setVideoSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)}];
            [dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:sampleBufferQueue];

            [_avSession addOutput:dataOutput];
            [_avSession commitConfiguration]; 
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%s - %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, exception.description);
        return FALSE;
    } @finally {
        return TRUE;
    }

}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    {
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

        CVMetalTextureRef texture = NULL;
        CVReturn status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm, width, height, 0, &texture);
        if(status == kCVReturnSuccess)
        {
            _metalView.drawableSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
            _texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture);
            _commandQueue = [_device newCommandQueue];
            CFRelease(texture);
        }
    }
}

- (void)drawInMTKView:(MTKView *)view {
    // creating command encoder
    if (_texture) {
        id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
        id<MTLTexture> drawingTexture = view.currentDrawable.texture;

        // set up and encode the filter
        MPSImageGaussianBlur *filter = [[MPSImageGaussianBlur alloc] initWithDevice:_device sigma:5];

        [filter encodeToCommandBuffer:commandBuffer sourceTexture:_texture destinationTexture:drawingTexture];

        // committing the drawing
        [commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable];
        [commandBuffer commit];
        _texture = nil;
    }
}

- (void)mtkView:(MTKView *)view drawableSizeWillChange:(CGSize)size {

}

@end
```

Comment: Opengles 3 vs Metal, how much is the difference in performance in this type of processing (if any)?

Comment: That question was answered in the 2015 WWDC presentation, "What's New in Metal, Part I," which you can watch at:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/603/

Comment: I had tried these codes. But I found that it would crash after serval seconds on "[commandBuffer commit]". How can I deal with it?